# @import .less file via url during compile

Tags: css, import, less

I've been looking around and have seen a lot of people asking about importing CSS or web fonts this way, but can't seem to find anything regarding the following:

I have a set of less files which are imported into a primary less file, some as reference and inline prior to the primary less, and some after the primary as inline. I am currently working with one site on a domain that houses the import less files, but I am also working on a site on another domain which I would like to use the same import less files.

I would like to be able to house the imported less files in a single location on a web server so that any updates will take effect when compiling the primary on a local machine.

So far my attempts at this:

```
@import url(//my.domain.com/style/my-styles.less);
@import (less) "//my.domain.com/style/my-styles.less";
```

has resulted in something along the lines of "/my.domain.com/style/my-styles.less wasn't found"

The sites I am working on are on a local intranet, hosted on VMs. I am using Crunch as my editor/compiler.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Comment: There's no problem to import Less files from a remote server ([demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40import%20%5C%22https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2Fseven-phases-max%2F9b9aa043e7909c9c1e51%2Fraw%2F5e64e4974a895db8f844b39b88cd7bcba7d795f3%2F2712.less%5C%22%3B%5Cn%22%7D)). Though you have to explicitly specify the domain (i.e. `http://...` or so).

Comment: No luck using "http://my.domain.com/style/my-styles.less". Maybe it is something to do with my environment or software? I've added more info on this to the main post.

Comment: "my.domain.com/style/my-styles.less" (or same with `//` shortcut) is not valid url on its own. As I already mentioned you have to specify protocol (`http://`, `https://`, `ftp://` etc.) explicitly. The compiler is not a part of a HTML page or a browser so it can't know what protocol to use for incomplete urls.

Comment: I was worried it might be the app. I'll look into other options later and have to deal with two versions of the import files for now. This will save me time from running down a bunch of dead-ends though. Thanks!